# cell.detailTextLabel not working

Tags: xcode, uitableview, detailtextlabel

I want to set up a textLabel and a detailTextLabel for my table. The textLabel is working properly. However, I couldnt get the detailTextLabel to display the text that I have set. Below is my code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.textLabel.text = @"SomeString";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"hello";

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What does it display instead?

Comment: It is not displaying anything... the label is blank

Comment: What's the value of `cell.detailTextLabel` at that point? Can you `NSLog` it or set a breakpoint and check it?

Comment: Have you configured the cell in the storyboard?

Comment: From the NSLog, it is a null value. I wonder why.

Comment: Sorry I am new to xcode.. how do you configure a cell in storyboard?

Comment: I found out the reason.. I put [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"]; in my viewDidLoad. When I remove this code, it works fine. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar issue as like @user1829700.

My initial settings are

> TableView --> Prototype Cell --> (Attribute Inspector) Style - set to
>   Custom (by design)

Changed Style to - Subtitle, it does the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Use appropriate UITableViewCellStyle with this (anything but UITableViewCellStyleDefault should thus work). The cell's style is specified when you initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

In your custom table cell implementation try adding @synthesize detailTextLabel;

Header (.h):

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *detailTextLabel;
```

Implementation (.m):

```
@synthesize textLabel;
@synthesize detailTextLabel;
```